# Why are the Continuous Wavelet Transforms of the same signal drastically different?

Tags: wavelet, stft

I'm currently studying wavelets and am running into confusion with regards to CWT coefficients. Ideally, I want a CWT algorithm that produces outputs similar to that of a STFT - i.e. produces coefficients that correspond to frequency magnitudes of the input signal. However, I'm finding conflicting results.

From the [CWT Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_wavelet_transform), I'm given the illustration below. This illustration shows that the wavelet coefficients are essentially just sampling different subbands of the signal. This is not what I'm looking for.

[image]

However, when I look at a [MATLAB web page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ug/continuous-and-discrete-wavelet-analysis.html) discussing the CWT and DWT, I find a different illustration of the CWT when operating on the same input signal. This diagram looks more similar to what I was hoping for where each frequency has a constant coefficient.

[image]

What is the difference between CWTs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are differences in axis-scales. However, I suspect that the main difference is that the first picture relates to either a real CWT (or time-frequency transform) or the real-part of a complex CWT (or time-frequency transform, again), while the second seems to be a magnitude.

In the first  image, the apparently wiggling part could "planified" by combining it to some imaginary part. Then changing the $y$-scale from linear to logarithmic could make the plots look closer.

Apart from representation issues (scales, magnitudes), with admissible continuous wavelets, there exists a wide variety thereof.  Factors that affect scalograms in practice are also the global shape of wavelets (symmetry and anti-symmetry for instance), their regularity, and the ways it is discretized (number and sampling of voices).